# KeyError: 'returnedbooks' when creating a new json file in python

Tags: python, class, methods

So I've created a ReturnedBook Class and wish to record a book being returned, this needs to be recording in json file (This file doesn't exist at present, so it needs creating and then appending to after the fact)

Here is my class and functions

```
returnedbooksJsonPath = 'returnedbooks.json'

    class ReturnedBook(BookItem):
      def __init__(self, book_id, returned_date):
        self.__book_id = book_id
        self.__returned_date = returned_date
    
      def get_returned_date(self):
        return self.__returned_date
    
      def get_book_id(self):
        return self.__book_id
    
      def record_returned_book(self):
        with open(returnedbooksJsonPath, 'a+') as returnedbooks:
          data['returnedbooks'].append({
            'book_id': self.__book_id,
            'returned_date': self.__returned_date,
          })
          json.dump(data, returnedbooks, indent=4, default=str)
    
        return "You have successfully returned the book"
    
    
    r = ReturnedBook("32", datetime.now())
    r.record_returned_book()
```

when I run this code I get a KeyError: returnedbooks

```
KeyError: 'returnedbooks'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18420/88328772.py in <module>
     25 
     26 r = ReturnedBook("32", datetime.now())
---> 27 r.record_returned_book()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18420/88328772.py in record_returned_book(self)
     15     with open(returnedbooksJsonPath, 'a+') as returnedbooks:
     16       header = [returnedbooks.readline().strip() for i in range(3)]
---> 17       data['returnedbooks'].append({
     18         'book_id': self.__book_id,
     19         'returned_date': self.__returned_date,

KeyError: 'returnedbooks'
```

My understanding of with open and using 'a+' is that it will create the file if it doesn't exist and then append the data? However, looking at this error, it creates the file, but then nothing gets written because the file is blank and there is no list/dictionary named 'returnedbooks' in the file it's blank?

Where have I gone wrong on the function please? Do I need to create an empty list named returnedbooks beforehand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `data` refer to?

Comment: ah... so I'm trying to create that data in the file, essentially the file doesn't exist at present, so I am trying to create it, then add that in

Comment: don't use class variables that start with a double underscore `__`, that's generally unpythonic. Instead define variables like `book_id` and just access them like `ret_book.book_id`, rather than creating a method for it. Another common Python idiom is to use properties to return internal attributes like `_book_id`, but unless you want to change what id is returned ex. based on a condition, then I think it's better to stick with just simple attributes in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm learning this through my uni degree and the double underscore was shown to us this way, but good to know now. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this figured out thanks to @rttr who shed some light on it. So I created a new list if the data was blank which then allows me to create the file and them append the data here is my solution

```
returnedbooksJsonPath = 'returnedbooks.json'

class ReturnedBook(BookItem):
  def __init__(self, member_id, book_id, returned_date):
    self.__member_id = member_id
    self.__book_id = book_id
    self.__returned_date = returned_date

  def get_returned_date(self):
    return self.__returned_date

  def get_book_id(self):
    return self.__book_id
  
  def member_id(self):
    return self.__member_id

  def record_returned_book(self):
    with open(returnedbooksJsonPath, 'a+') as returnedbooks:
      data = returnedbooks.read()
      if data == '':
          data = {
            'returnedbooks': []
          }
          data['returnedbooks'].append({
          'member' : self.__member_id,
          'book_id': self.__book_id,
          'returned_date': self.__returned_date,
        })
      json.dump(data, returnedbooks, indent=4, default=str)

    return "You have successfully returned the book"


r = ReturnedBook("10", "32", datetime.now())
r.record_returned_book()
```